# Clientside load balancing for grpc v1.34.1, nameResolverFactory is deprecated

Tags: java, load-balancing, grpc, grpc-java

I am using grpc v1.34.1 with Java and it's hard to configure client-side load balancing since some of the methods are deprecated in this version. It was pretty straightforward to configure client-side load balancing in an earlier version by:

```
final ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(target)
        .nameResolverFactory(new DnsNameResolverProvider())  // this is on by default
        .loadBalancerFactory(RoundRobinLoadBalancerFactory.getInstance())
        .usePlaintext(true)
        .build();
```

Or by this https://sultanov.dev/blog/grpc-client-side-load-balancing/

But, there aren't any references available for a newer version that has deprecated `nameResolverFactory` and removed method `loadBalancerFactory`.

```
NameResolver.Factory nameResolverFactory = new MultiAddressNameResolverFactory(
        new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 50000),
        new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 50001),
        new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 50002)
);

channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget("localhost")
        .nameResolverFactory(nameResolverFactory)
        .defaultLoadBalancingPolicy("round_robin")
        .usePlaintext()
        .build();
```

Client-side load balancing works. But, the newer API has deprecated `nameResolverFactory`.

Could anyone please point me towards the alternative of `nameResolverFactory` in the newer version for client-side load balancing with different servers (hosts and ports)?

Comment: `defaultLoadBalancingPolicy()` is the correct way. I don't see anything obviously wrong. There's a slim chance your target string is being misinterpreted; you can try prefixing it with `dns:///` to guarantee the DnsNameResolver is used. We wouldn't expect any real load balancing for "localhost", so I assume that you normally use `target`. How are you verifying if load balancing is working?

Comment: I have a java client which calls a NodeJs server. Since NodeJs is single threaded, I have multiple instances running of it using pm2. NodeJS is performing CPU intensive task. Therefore, a spike in one of the process can be easily noticed. But, all other servers are idle with 0% utilization.

Comment: As a workaround, I have created multiple channels and stubs and I pick one of them randomly to connect to server. This gives a higher chance to hit replicas of server(different instances)

Comment: If your multiple channels/stubs code is working with the same target string then that means DNS is set up properly to return multiple entries for your target. In that case your `defaultLoadBalancingPolicy` should also work.

Comment: @San P Unfortunately, it didn't work. I created channel object in constructor and reusing it to avoid recreation of channel with `target` and `defaultLoadBalancingPolicy`  as it's costly. But, I create a new stub for every call.

Comment: @NitishBhardwaj, are you using passing the same target value (`forTarget(target)`) in both cases?

Comment: @EricAnderson Yes

Comment: I don't see any behavior that would have changed between the two APIs. But I do see a potential issue with the test and how `round_robin` behaves. `round_robin` connects to all backends and round-robins over the _connected_ backends. Whichever backend connects first will receive any queued traffic at that point. In your test, you do multiple RPCs in parallel on an idle Channel; those will likely all be buffered and thus go to the same backend the moment it connects. Try doing the test RPCs serially and see if you still need multiple channels.

Comment: @EricAnderson I will surely try it out and share the results. But, the only difference I could see is that the newer API doesn't have a way to specify multiple server IP and ports which could be used to balance the load at client side.

Comment: Hi @EricAnderson I ran a test by using a single channel to make serial RPCs calls to servers. Turns out that just a single server is used to handle all requests (being 90% used) and all other server are idle (0% used). I noticed this by `pm2 monit`. I still believe that there should be someway in the newer API to specify different server hosts for client-side load balancing like it used to be in earlier versions.

Comment: Updated the question to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After going through grpc-java internal implementation, I found that that the newer version accepts the `NameResolver.Factory` object in slightly different way. It's encapsulated to `NameResolverProvider` which is required to be registered to default `NameResolverRegistry`. Sample code to do this in newer version is shared below:

```
NameResolverProvider nameResolverFactory = new MultiAddressNameResolverFactory(
                new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 50000),
                new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 50001),
                new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 50002)
        );

NameResolverRegistry nameResolverRegistry = NameResolverRegistry.getDefaultRegistry();
nameResolverRegistry.register(nameResolverFactory);
channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget("localhost")
          .defaultLoadBalancingPolicy("round_robin")
          .usePlaintext()
          .build();


public class MultiAddressNameResolverFactory extends NameResolverProvider {
    final List<EquivalentAddressGroup> addresses;

    MultiAddressNameResolverFactory(SocketAddress... addresses) {
        this.addresses = Arrays.stream(addresses)
                .map(EquivalentAddressGroup::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public NameResolver newNameResolver(URI notUsedUri, NameResolver.Args args) {
        return new NameResolver() {
            @Override
            public String getServiceAuthority() {
                return "fakeAuthority";
            }
            public void start(Listener2 listener) {
                listener.onResult(ResolutionResult.newBuilder().setAddresses(addresses).setAttributes(Attributes.EMPTY).build());
            }
            public void shutdown() {
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String getDefaultScheme() {
        return "multiaddress";
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isAvailable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected int priority() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

By default, your custom implementation for NameResolver.Factory would be picked up by channel to connect to server. Based on the load balancing policy, a `SocketAddress` would be picked up to connect to server.

Comment: You can use service locator to register the provider, add a text file META-INF/services/io.grpc.NameResolverProvider  containing one line being your fully qualified MultiAddressNameResolverFactory class name

Answer (score 0):

just one thing to add to Nitish Bhardwaj answer, for me method

```
int priority()
```

did not work with value 0, because io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolverProvider has the value of 5 and io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.UdsNameResolverProvider has the value of 3, which in my case was not setting my custom NameResolverProvider, I could fix it to be automatically picking up my custom NameResolverProvider by overriding method `priority()` to anything more than 5.

full code:

```
package iam.mfa.grpc.client.resolvers;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

import io.grpc.Attributes;
import io.grpc.EquivalentAddressGroup;
import io.grpc.NameResolver;
import io.grpc.NameResolverProvider;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

/**
 * @author HAMMA FATAKA (mfataka@monetplus.cz)
 * @project gRPC
 * @date 07.04.2023 21:54
 */
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
public class MultipleAddressNameResolverProvider extends NameResolverProvider {
    private final List<EquivalentAddressGroup> addresses;

    @Override
    public NameResolver newNameResolver(URI targetUri, NameResolver.Args args) {
        return new NameResolver() {
            @Override
            public String getServiceAuthority() {
                return "noAuthority";
            }


            @Override
            public void start(Listener2 listener) {
                listener.onResult(ResolutionResult.newBuilder().setAddresses(addresses).setAttributes(Attributes.EMPTY).build());
            }

            @Override
            public void shutdown() {

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String getDefaultScheme() {
        return "multiTarget";
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isAvailable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected int priority() {
        return 6;
    }
}
```

Client config:

```
package iam.mfa.grpc.client.config;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import iam.mfa.grpc.client.resolvers.MultipleAddressNameResolver;
import io.grpc.EquivalentAddressGroup;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.NameResolverRegistry;
import io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver;
import io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder;

/**
 * @author HAMMA FATAKA (mfataka@monetplus.cz)
 * @project gRPC
 * @date 26.02.2023 16:03
 */
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

    @Value("#{'${grpc.client.targets}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> targets;


    @PostConstruct
    public void initNameResolver(){
        final var addresses = targets.stream()
                .map(target -> {
                    final var splitTarget = target.split(":");
                    final var host = splitTarget[0];
                    final var port = splitTarget[1];
                    return new EquivalentAddressGroup(new InetSocketAddress(host, Integer.parseInt(port)));
                })
                .toList();
        final var nameResolverFactory = MultipleAddressNameResolver.of(addresses);
        NameResolverRegistry.getDefaultRegistry().register(nameResolverFactory);
    }


    @Bean
    public ManagedChannel channel() {
        return NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget("localhost")
                .defaultLoadBalancingPolicy("round_robin")
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();
    }

}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: If you make the target match the provider scheme, does that not avoid the ambiguity between providers and negate the need to fallback on ordering? 
 e.g. on client `NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget("multiTarget://localhost")`